# ssh and wpa_supplicant.conf files not getting deleted on boot?

Tags: boot, ssh, raspbian-stretch, pi-zero-w, wpa

I am following this guide for the raspberry pi zero w: https://core-electronics.com.au/tutorials/raspberry-pi-zerow-headless-wifi-setup.html

I've flashed the latest raspbian stretch lite to the SD card already. I then added the ssh and wpa_supplicant files to the boot directory as seen here:

[image]

Lastly, the wpa_supplicant.conf file has these contents:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="placeholder"
    psk="placeholder"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

However, when I boot my raspberry pi zero w, it doesn't attempt to connect to my wifi (the logs for my router are empty) and never deletes the two files from the boot directory as they supposedly should be. Am I doing something wrong in the setup?

Answer (score 1):

You need to scan the ssid to be sure it can connect to your wifi. scan_ssid=1 at the network branch. Your wpa_supplicant.conf file should be like this:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="placeholder"
    psk="placeholder"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

I would say that key_mgmt=WPA-PSK part can be deleted. It should be resolved when scanning.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have done anything. Realistically, if nothing was going wrong with the boot, shouldn't the ssh file at the very least get deleted? From what I've read, it can have whatever in it; the mere existence of the file will apply a config change.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it by flashing an older version of Raspbian Jessie as was said in the original guide. Figured that Stretch would also do the job, but suppose not.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I fixed it by flashing an older version of Raspbian Jessie as was said in the original guide. Figured that Stretch would also do the job, but suppose not.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.